# How to load local font in php instead of google font with Variable

Tags: php, css, wordpress, variables, google-fonts

With the GDPR hitting hard I have to remove google fonts that are loaded per Link from Google Servers.

I have a wordpress theme that has those links everwhere.
I am not very good at php, but in this theme I have this link:

```
  $open_sans_font_url = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,300,400,600&subset=$subsets&display=fallback";
}
```

I puts the loaded font into a var. I need to change this so it will load the font from my local font folder.

The problem is, I don't know how to change the link in a way that it will load all the font and font weights/styles. Is it possible? And maybe it is easy but I can't change the whole php file - not enough knowledge from my side and I don't want to risk destroying the theme.

(I know about @font-face and css but not how to add as a link in a var)

I appreciate any help - thank you!

Comment: as an aside, in what way are these fonts subject to GDPR, which is a data privacy law? I'm intrigued at what the logic is here. Do they arrive with tracking cookies or something?

Comment: in Europe where I am from, we are not allowed (or at least there where juristical problems and uncertainties) to use Google fonts loaded from US Servers because of the US cloud act which allows US to use and gather data from clients per this connection. Better save than sorry says my superior. @ADyson

Comment: I also am in a country subject to GDPR. That's the first I've heard of it. Is that the opinion of a professional lawyer with relevant expertise? You can probably rule out loading anything from half the useful places on the web if that's your approach. Normally sites simply ask people what cookies etc they want to allow - it's sufficient to let them have the choice, rather than simply remove it. Have you verified that these files actually come with any tracking when loaded into your site?

Comment: Also, IMHO "better safe than sorry" sounds like a way to put arbitrary barriers in your way, rather than a considered approach driven by genuine advice and evidence. Not saying it's wrong necessarily, but have you / your superior actually checked?

Comment: I know or we know that it is not really clear but we had  some problems with lawyers who used the loophole to get money. Yes, apparently there needs to be a decision but some of our clients want this fixed right away so nothing can hit them. We need to talk about "ask what cookie"-solution, which will be a paid cookie banner because free ones are not good enough at the moment. But for now it has to be local fonts. Here is some information:[link]
https://cookie-script.com/blog/google-fonts-and-gdpr
Clients want it fixed but don't want to pay. So here I am. @ADyson

Comment: Hmm, that link says _"To send you the font, the Google server has to know where to send it, so it needs to collect website users' IP addresses_" ...but that's just a description of how the HTTP protocol works. It applies to every webpage ever created. If they're _storing_ those addresses without explicit consent _and_ combining it with other data they may hold in order to try and track individuals, then that's different, but the link offers no particular evidence of that. Again, doesn't mean it's not happening, but that article is a bit thin, if you ask me. But I'm not a lawyer either, so...

Comment: ...the court case is interesting, but my understanding of GDPR is as long as you let the user know and the processing is for a reasonable, legitimate purpose (such as returning the data to the correct place) then it ought to be ok. Anything further might require more explicit consent. Obviously it's google so they almost certainly do combine the data with other stuff to enhance their general spidering of your everyday life, so yeah it might be simpler to disable it for now at least until you can get a consent screen sorted.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to simply replace the variable since it links to a CSS file. There's two options on what you can do. Due to the lack of more code, I can only describe how to do this and not provide direct examples.

### Method one: Using your existing CSS, remove the variable

You can add the OpenSans font to your own CSS with the mentioned @font-face, and then remove where the `$open_sans_font_url` variable is used.

It's likely that this variable is only used to create a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="...">` tag to include the Google Font. If you remove this stylesheet inclusion and other possible usages of the variable, you're no longer using Google Fonts.

### Method two: Use your own CSS file with the font-face

For this, you need to create your own CSS file, for example `opensans.css`, with the font-face loaded in. You can then use the Wordpress function `get_template_directory_uri()` to get the address of your new CSS file within the theme like this:

`$open_sans_font_url  = get_template_directory_uri() . '/opensans.css';`

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you in advance! I will try both methods. The problem is that I have various php files from different sources in the mentioned theme, and some plugins (yes it's an old website and theme). Each php file just loads the google font for something. I could post all the files where the font is loaded (mind you it's not always the same way). I am not so good at php (yet :) ) that I can read the code an know what the link does and where. But @thomasberends I have one Var and different weights, and I need all in one var, just like it does in the google link.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it by switching to BunnyCDN Fonts, a clone of Google Fonts that (unlike Google Fonts) process requests completely anonymously.

https://fonts.bunny.net

https://css-tricks.com/bunny-fonts/